# Перевести миллионы в красивый вид на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть число вида 4584895. Надо на js перевести в 4,6 млн.
Желательно на нативном js, максимум jquery.
Какие есть варианты?

Был такой вариант, но он ужасен и был брошен на полпути:

```
var num = '123456789';
var arrNum = num.split('');
var numAfter = (Math.round((arrNum.splice(-6).join('')) / 100000) * 100000).toString().replace(/0/g, '');
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вариант - написать код самому.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let myNumber = 4584895,
    myFixedNumber = (myNumber/1000000).toFixed(1),
    myMillion = myFixedNumber + ' млн';
    
console.log( myMillion );
```

Comment: молодец - красиво !

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log( "123 →", shortenNumRu(123) );
console.log( "123456 →", shortenNumRu(123456) );
console.log( "123456789 →", shortenNumRu(123456789) );
console.log( "1234567890 →", shortenNumRu(1234567890) );
console.log( shortenNumRu("Moo...") );

function shortenNumRu(num) {
  if( isNaN(num) ) throw new Error(num + " is not a Number!");

  let bubu = {
    "0": "",
    "1": " тыс.",
    "2": " млн",
    "3": " млрд",
  };

  let thousands = Math.floor( (("" + num).length - 1) / 3 );
  
  let coef = 1000 ** thousands;
  
  return ( num / coef ).toFixed(1) + bubu[ thousands ];
}
```

Домашнее задание: Добавить условие, удаляющее `.0` в конце))

Comment: а в чём разница между 123.0 и 123.5 ?

Comment: @MaximLensky * 123.5 было округлением от 123456 ) Чуть изменил вывод.

Comment: в первом примере наверно 0 убрать надо .., а то получется цифра.цифра в обои примерах

Comment: А это точно нативный JS? Или библиотека использована, дело то не шуточное...

Comment: `<grammar_nazi>` После "млн" и "млрд" точка не нужна.`</grammar_nazi>` :)